# Interpreting the evaluation result of multiple linear regression

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

I am learning the multiple linear regression model.
I've built a `model` and using R command:

```
summary(model)
```

I got this result:

```
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 253.2 on 44 degrees of freedom Multiple
R-squared:  0.3336, Adjusted R-squared:  0.2579  F-statistic: 4.405 on
5 and 44 DF,  p-value: 0.002444
```

How can I interpret this result in order to have a decision regarding the goodness of the model? In specific, what is the `44 degrees of freedom` means for this case?

Also, why do we have adjusted and multiple r squared parameters?

Comment: you need to give input on how did you do it and what are the number of data elements to help others offer help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am going to answer your questions one after another.

**First, what do the 44 degrees of freedom mean?**

It simply means that the model you built is constructed by using 44 independent variables. For example a model that looks like y = a*x + b has 1 independent variable (i.e. a) and thus 1 degree of freedom. A model that looks like y= a*x1 + b*x2 + c would have 2 independent variables (i.e. a and b) and thus 2 degrees of freedom.

**Second, what is the Multiple R-squared?**

Here for the purpose of interpretating it Multiple R-squared is equivalent to the (simple) R-squared you would have for a linear regression model with 1 degree of freedom. Multiple R-squared tells us the share of the observed variance that is explained by the model. For example if you have a Multiple R-squared of 0.79 it means that your model explains 79% of the observed variance in your data.

**Third, what is the Adjusted R-squared and why do we need it?**

There are several problems with Multiple R-squared.

**Problem 1:** Every time you add a predictor to a model, the R-squared increases, even if due to chance alone. It never decreases. Consequently, a model with more independent variables (more degrees of freedom) may appear to have a better fit simply because it has more independent variables.

**Problem 2:** If a model has too many predictors and higher order polynomials, it begins to model the random noise in the data. This condition is known as overfitting the model and misleadingly high R-squared values and a lessened ability to make predictions.

Problem 1 is caused by Problem 2. And this is where Adjusted R-squared is coming in handy. Adjusted R-squared is an attempt at fixing these problems by factoring in the number of independent variables. The adjusted R-squared tells you the percentage of variation explained by only the independent variables that actually affect the dependent variable.

[image]

where:

- n is the number of data points you have,
- and k is the number of independent variables used to explain their distribution, excluding the constant

If you add more and more useless variables to a model, adjusted r-squared will decrease. If you add more useful variables, adjusted r-squared will increase.
Adjusted R-squared  will always be less than or equal to R-squared . You only need R-squared when working with samples. In other words, R-squared  isn’t necessary when you have data from an entire population.

---

Here is an interesting series of articles which will help you understand how to use R-squared to interpret the results of your model even better.

- [Regression Analysis: How Do I Interpret R-squared and Assess the Goodness-of-Fit?](http://blog.minitab.com/blog/adventures-in-statistics/regression-analysis-how-do-i-interpret-r-squared-and-assess-the-goodness-of-fit)
- [Multiple Regression Analysis: Use Adjusted R-Squared and Predicted R-Squared to Include the Correct Number of Variables](http://blog.minitab.com/blog/adventures-in-statistics/multiple-regession-analysis-use-adjusted-r-squared-and-predicted-r-squared-to-include-the-correct-number-of-variables)

Answer (score 2):

The details are just a `help(summary.lm)` in R. The meaning of the codes and the terms are as follows:

Considering R = Correlation Coefficient

1. The **residual standard error** is nothing more than the positive square root of the mean square error.
2. **Regression degrees of freedom** = number of independent variables (factors) in $y$ = $a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 + a_3x3 + ...$   [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degrees_of_freedom_%28statistics%29) for a better in-depth explanation
3. **R Square** = $(Multiple R)^2$ = $R^2$ =  $1 - (Residual SS / Total SS) = (Regress SS / Total SS)$
4. **Adjusted R Square** = $1 - (Total df / Residual df)(Residual SS / Total SS)$

A [wonderful post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/17148/84191) on how to understand degrees of freedom.